# How do i test www to non-www forwarding?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, request-headers

I'm using html5 boilerplate and I'm trying to test if my htaccess is working properly. When I type in www.domain.com into chrome or firefox it does not redirect. I'm thinking maybe this is just some browser gimmick though, similar to how Chrome hides the http:// even though its there.

I have checked using chrome dev tools and firebug, and under the request headers it shows whatever I enter in as the "Host"... both with www. and without it... so I dont really know if its working

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Suppress or force the "www." at the beginning of URLs
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The rule is OK. 1) Did you enabled mod_rewrite in your .htaccess via `RewriteEngine On`? 2) Is mod_rewrite module loaded in Apache at all? Try moving your instructions outside of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` to see if it will generate any server errors (indication that mod_rewrite is not loaded). 3) Check if .htaccess is allowed to be used.

Comment: I did not. I am a tard. I didnt see the spot above about rewrite engine.

Comment: Which is generally more preferred, www or non? I notice a lot of major sites use www (facebook, amazon, etc), even though people say non-www is "nicer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is OK.

Please check the following:

- Did you **enabled** mod_rewrite in your .htaccess via `RewriteEngine On`?
- Is mod_rewrite module **loaded** in Apache at all? Try moving your instructions outside of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` to see if it will generate any server errors (indication that mod_rewrite is not loaded).
- Check if **.htaccess** is allowed to be used.

---

As to **www or non** -- see these topics on Webmasters part of StackExchange:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/507/should-i-include-www-in-my-canonical-urls-what-are-the-pros-and-cons
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11925/to-www-or-not-to-www
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14457/what-does-www-do
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11560/seo-preference-for-www-or-http-protocol-redirection-do-www-websites-rank-bett
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/is-was-seo-the-only-reason-to-force-the-www-on-domain-names
- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15290/does-it-matter-that-our-website-cant-be-found-without-the-www